# Backbone.sync – Collection using ajax as well as Socket.IO/WebSockets

Tags: api, rest, backbone.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a Backbone application, which has a collection called `Links`. `Links` maps to a REST API URI of `/api/links`.

The API will give the user the latest links. However, I have a system in place that will add a job to the message queue when the user hits this API, requesting that the links in the database are updated.

When this job is finished, I would to **push** the new links to the Backbone collection.

How should I do this? In my mind I have two options:

- From the Backbone collection, long poll the API for new links
- Setup WebSockets to send a "message" to the collection when the job is done, sending the new data with it
- Scrap the REST API for my application and just use WebSockets for everything, as I am likely to have more realtime needs later down the line

### WebSockets with the REST API

If I use WebSockets, I'm not sure of the best way to integrate this into my Backbone collection so that it works alongside the REST API.

At the moment my Backbone collection looks like this:

```
var Links = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/api/links'
});
```

I'm not sure how to enable the Backbone collection to handle AJAX **and** WebSockets. Do I continue to use the default Backbone.sync for the CRUD Ajax operations, and then deal with the single WebSocket connection manually? In my mind:

```
var Links = Backbone.Collection.extend({
  url: '/api/links',
  initialize: function () {
    var socket = io.connect('http://localhost');
    socket.on('newLinks', addLinks)
  },
  addLinks: function (data) {
    // Prepend `data` to the collection
  };
})
```

### Questions

How should I implement my realtime needs, from the options above or any other ideas you have? Please provide examples of code to give some context.

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/logicalparadox/backbone.iobind

Comment: @PaulHoenecke I have, but I'm not sure how to make a collection "get links" initially via WebSockets, and then when there are more available (when the job is finished), "get more links." If you get me? Backbone.ioBind appears to map the CRUD operations to Sockets but I'm still not sure how my collection would look for my use case (described in original post).

Comment: @PaulHoenecke Just realised how I should do that using the `serverChange` method shown in the docs. However, this means I would need to transfer my whole API to WebSockets. Is that a good thing?!

Comment: Not sure you would need to. If you dont use the replacement `sync`, you can continue using the REST API for normal CRUD. Then listen for some socket event which you emit from the server and possibly call `myCollection.update(dataFromSocket)` where `myCollection` was previously synced using normal fetch via REST.

Answer (score 1):

No worries! [Backbone.WS](https://github.com/ydaniv/backbone-ws) got you covered.

You can init a WebSocket connection like:

```
var ws = new Bakcbone.WS('ws://exmaple.com/');
```

And bind a Model to it like:

```
var model = new Backbone.Model();
ws.bind(model);
```

Then this model will listen to messages events with the type `ws:message` and you can call `model.send(data)` to send data via that connection.

Of course the same goes for Collections.

Backbone.WS also gives some tools for mapping a custom REST-like API to your Models/Collections.

Answer (score 0):

My company has a fully Socket.io based solution using backbone, primarily because we want our app to "update" the gui when changes are made on another users screen in real time.

In a nutshell, it's a can of worms.  Socket.IO works well, but it also opens a lot of doors you may not be interested in seeing behind.  Backbone events get quite out of whack because they are so tightly tied to the ajax transactions...you're effectively overriding that default behavior.  One of our better hiccups has been deletes, because our socket response isn't the model that changed, but the entire collection, for example.  Our solution does go a bit further than most, because transactions are via a DDL that is specifically setup to be universal across the many devices we need to be able to communicate with, now and in the future.

If you do go the ioBind path, beware that you'll be using different methods for change events compared to your non-socket traffic (if you mix and match)  That's the big drawback of that method, standard things like "change" becomes "update" for example to avoid collisions.  It can get really confusing in late-night debug or when you have a new developer join the team.  For that reason, I prefer either going sockets, or not, not a combination.  Sockets have been good so far, and scary fast.

We use a base function that does the heavy lifting, and have several others that extend this base to give us the transaction functionality we need.

[This article](http://swizec.com/blog/elegantly-using-socket-io-in-backbone-apps/swizec/5712) gives a great starter for the method we used.